# IPB forum post background color

Tags: html, css, ipb

I have been curious about something on my IPB forum that hopefully someone can clear up for me, if it is even possible.

Say for example I have certain users on the forum who are designated as "moderators" of some sort (some for different groups but still moderators).  Is it possible somewhere to make all posts by moderators (and maybe even separate for each section of moderator) to have post background colors?

What I mean is, the color of the text would be the same as the default by all members, but the background for their post, behind the text, would be shaded/colored a different color to better distinguish when that member posts.

If this is possible, any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!